# AngularJs 1.3.11 - Directive is not updating html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-controller

Directive Template (Template.html):

```
<div class="someContainer">
<div ng-repeat="obj in data" >
    <a href="{{obj.linkUrl}}" target="{{obj.linkTarget}}">
      </a>
</div>
```

AngularJs Directive:

```
module some.directives {
    'use strict';

    interface MyScope extends ng.IScope {
        data: any;
    }

    class SomeDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        static instance(): ng.IDirective {
            return new SomeDirective;
        }

        restrict = 'E';
        templateUrl = 'Template.html';
        scope = {
            data: '='
        };
        link(scope: MyScope,
            element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
            ): void {

            scope.$watch('data',() => {
                console.log("changed, new val: ", scope.data);
            });

        }
    }

    angular
        .module('some.directives')
        .directive('somedirective', SomeDirective.instance);
}
```

It Is Called like this:

```
 <section>
                <somedirective data="model.data"></somedirective>
           </section>
```

It is Important to note that: in console.log, the scope is successfully changed, but the ng-repeat seems not to update. Can you help me out?

Comment: Nothing in code shown would update the data. How is it being done? What are expected results? Question is not clear. My guess is you are changing scope from outside of angular and need to notify angular to run digest

Comment: The data is being updated by a controller which is beyond the scope of the question, that's why it was omitted. The results I am expecting is that everytime the data is updated, the ng-repeat is executed to update the new data. I am not changing the scope from outside of angular.

Comment: Nothing in code shown would present a problem though. Issue lies beyond the code shown

Comment: You are missing a close </div> tag in your template, though I'm not sure if that is the problem or not.

Comment: Check out the working sample http://plnkr.co/edit/iOYi8i9kbMfEdFpVozoa?p=preview. However, it is not TypeScript

Comment: Don't you need to `compile` the template or something?